# Story Identification for alien abduction novel, pre 1993

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-abduction

This was a novel that my father read in junior english, which for him would have been 1993. He describes the intro of the book to be a middle aged man, who's appearance was pudgy and not particularly attractive, who was abducted by "ugly aliens". Once the man saw and compared himself to the aliens he felt more attractive even though he'd describe his own body as "looking like a coca cola bottle". All the female aliens found him very attractive and even the male aliens "admired him". That's as much as my father can remember and I haven't had much luck finding anything similar to that description, though I am very poorly versed in sci-fi literature. If anyone can help me find what book he read in high school, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In [Slaughterhouse Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaughterhouse-Five) Billy is described as: *He was a funny-looking child who became a funny-looking youth—tall and weak, and shaped like a bottle of Coca-Cola*. Billy is abducted by the Tralfamadorians, however there are no female Tralfamadorians to find him attractive. I suppose it's just possible this is the novel your father remembers, though it would take quite some mis-remembering.

Comment: Wow, I think this could be it! You'd have to take into consideration that this was a time my father was an immigrant still learning English and this was the real first English class he had been thrown into. I shared these details with him and he says the character of Montana Wildhack definitely rang a bell. More than anything he remembers that Coca-Cola quote, so I do imagine you've found the story he was telling me about! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like this is [Slaughterhouse Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaughterhouse-Five) by Kurt Vonnegut.

The protagonist, *Billy Pilgrin*, is described as:

> He was a funny-looking child who became a funny-looking youth—tall and weak, and shaped like a bottle of Coca-Cola.

Billy is abducted by aliens called the Tralfamadorians who are indeed weird looking, but there are no female Tralfamadorians to find him attractive. However the Tralfamadorians also kidnap an actress *Montana Wildhack* to keep him company and they end up falling in love.